# Unable to retrieve location using 'LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER' even when WiFi is enabled in device running android M

Tags: android, location, android-6.0-marshmallow, locationmanager, google-location-services

I'm trying to retrieve location using `LocationManager` following [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/) tutorial.

I'm running the code on an android device running Marshmallow and I have checked the permission and running below code once the permission is granted.

Here's my code:

```
public Location getLocation() {
        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // getting GPS status
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            // getting network status
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
                // no network provider is enabled

                Log.d("noProviderEnabled", "called");

            } else {
                this.canGetLocation = true;
                // First get location from Network Provider
                if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("Network", "Network");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            currentLatDouble = location.getLatitude();
                            currentLngDouble = location.getLongitude();

                        }
                    }
                }
                // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
                if (isGPSEnabled) {
                    if (location == null) {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                        Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            location = locationManager
                                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            if (location != null) {
                                currentLatDouble = location.getLatitude();
                                currentLngDouble = location.getLongitude();

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return location;
    }
```

Even though WiFi is enabled, `isNetworkEnabled=locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);` is returning `false` and `Log.d("noProviderEnabled", "called");` is getting printed out.

**Update:** when I turned the `GPS` on and then run the above code.. only the `isNetworkEnabled` returned `true` and `isGPSEnabled` still returned `false`.

What's wrong here? Why am I unable to retrieve location using `LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER` even when WiFi is enabled?

P.S.: This is working perfectly fine on android L and below.

Comment: Did you get any solution ?

Comment: @faisal1208 nope... what I did was to use GPS_PROVIDER instead.

Comment: So your code is working now ?

Comment: @faisal1208 yes, it is.

Comment: Ok i have also implemented the code but the coordinates are not correct

Comment: @faisal1208 try to restart the phone

Comment: Many a times i have restarted my phone

Comment: try to follow this github sample: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135966/discussion-between-faisal1208-and-hammad-nasir).